# Debugging remote plugin (Invalid channel)

Tags: neovim, python, neovim-python-client

I wrote a neovim remote plugin.
I get this message after the command finished ( when I try another).

```
Error detected while processing function remote#define#request:
line    2:
Error invoking 'C:/Users/ekarni/.vim/plugged/speech-to-text.nvim/rplugin/python/main.py:command:Voice' on channel 5:
Invalid channel: 5
```

How can I debug it?
What causes  this kind of failure?

(There was no direct exception, and I tried to make sure there was indirect exception in one of the corresponding futures using (try..catch) )

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem with a simpler version of the plugin that you could share? Solving a problem without being able to reproduce it is difficult :-/